# Share point unique values

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2016

Can you please suggest how to check the unique values from entire share point site to avoid duplicates records. I was able to find only for a list with option "Enforce unique values" so that i have enabled this it not allows duplicate record in that list. is there any way to compare in all the lists?

Answer (score 1):

"Enforce unique values" setting is based on a list or library **column**.

Then I create a site column and set it to "Yes",test if this could avoid duplicate records of this column in all lists:

[image]

However, this will only limit the values on one list or library. If multiple lists use the same site column and fill in the same value, nothing happens.

So there is no such way to enforce unique values in all lists.